# How to set the background color of new activity after clicking tabs

Tags: android, tabs

I am switching activities on tab clicks and successful at this. But, in one of my Activity class I am doing the following:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

main.xml has the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#BDBDBD">
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to change the background of this layout only and I want tabs to their as it is. But with the current  `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` in main.xml my background is overwriting the tabs which means I am unable to see tabs. and If I make `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` I cannot see any change taking and tabs are still their.

Please help.

---

Here is some information..
screen2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView android:text="AcctId" 
                android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
                android:layout_width="50px" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/acctid" 
                android:layout_width="200px" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:text="Zip" 
                android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
                android:layout_width="50px" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/stid" 
                android:layout_width="200px" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button android:text="Login"
            android:layout_width="80px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
        </Button>
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="200px"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

screen1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#c6c3c6"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingTop="1dip"
        android:paddingLeft="1dip"
        android:paddingRight="1dip">

    <TabWidget
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class onstarAndroidMain extends TabActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
    addTabs();
    }

    private void addTabs(){
    Resources resources = getResources();

    TabHost tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabs.setup();

    //tabspec defines the attributes of the tab
    TabSpec tab;


    tab = tabs.newTabSpec("Screen1");
    tab.setContent(new Intent(this, Screen1.class));
    tab.setIndicator("Screen1");
    tabs.addTab(tab);
    tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 30;

    tab = tabs.newTabSpec("Screen2");
    tab.setContent(new Intent(this, Screen2.class));
    tab.setIndicator("Screen2");
    tabs.addTab(tab);
    tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 30;

    tab = tabs.newTabSpec("Screen3");
    tab.setContent(new Intent(this, Screen3.class));
    tab.setIndicator("Screen3");
    tabs.addTab(tab);
    tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 30;

    //sets the current tab
    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
    //add the tabhost to the main content view

    }
}
```

Screen2.java

```
public class OnstarScreen2 extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
}
```

Now whenever I click the screen2 tab and try to get the screen2.xml, my tabs are going below the screen2 layout. I dont know what to do. Basically what I want to achieve is that the tab should be always their at the bottom irrespective of what view is shown above them. they should not be overlapped with anything else.

screen2.xml has a scrollview and iside that I have a linearlayout which has a login form...but this form whenever is called just comes above the tabs...please help

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931077/how-to-set-the-background-color-of-new-activity-after-clicking-tab

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong with your tabs. Are you just launching a new activity when the tab is clicked? Then, if that new activitys layout covers the entire screen, ofcourse the tabs will be covered by this.

Follow this guide:
http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: Now If I waned to launch a webview with one of my tabs and I want the tab content to be still visible then what should I do..coz without specifying the layout_height and weight as fill_parent I cannot get the webview working ..I am kind of confused..

Comment: follow the link i posted? ._. i cant help you from the limited information you have given