# How to set the background color of new activity after clicking tabs

Tags: android

I am switching activities on tab clicks and successful at this. But, in one of my Activity class I am doing the following: 
`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.main);}`

main.xml has the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#BDBDBD"
>
```

I want to change the background of this layout only and I want tabs to their as it is. But with the currentandroid:layout_height="fill_parent"in main.xml my background is overwriting the tabs which means I am unable to see tabs. and If I makeandroid:layout_height="wrap_content"` I cannot see any change taking and tabs are still their.

Answer (score 0):

Try using two views inside a main view.

For example:

-> LinearLayout (parent)
---> LinearLayout (with tabs)
---> LinearLayout (with main content)

That way you can set the background of the main content window in XML or by using `myListView.setBackgroundColor()`